# electron run page with flash player

Tags: electron

I make a browser with ELECTRO and need run webpage with flash. Above my code man.js
How can config this code for run flash player? I put .dll flash player beside the code out the folder

```
const {app, BrowserWindow, webContents, session, Tray} = require('electron')
let mainWindow, secundaryWindow, tray
function createTray(){

tray = new Tray('trayTemplate@2x.png')
tray.setToolTip('Referente ao browser')
tray.on('click', e =>{
    
    if(e.shiftKey){ //Se usar o botão shift ele fecha o tray
        app.quit()
    }else{
        mainWindow.isVisible() ? mainWindow.hide() : mainWindow.show() 
    }
    
})  
}
const {ipcMain} = require('electron');
function createWindow () {
  createTray()
  let ses = session.defaultSession
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
width: 1600, height: 800,
minWidth: 800, minHeight: 600,
icon: 'trayTemplate@2x.ico',
webPreferences: {
  'plugins': true,
  contextIsolation: false,
  nodeIntegration: true
}
  })
mainWindow.setMenu(null)
  app.commandLine.appendSwitch('ppapi-flash-path', 'pepflashplayer.dll')
app.commandLine.appendSwitch('ppapi-flash-version', '29.0 r0')
mainWindow.loadURL('http://www.ardisialabs.com/demo/')
  mainWindow.on('closed',  () => {
mainWindow = null
  })
 let wc = mainWindow.webContents
 wc.on('new-window', (e, url) => {
console.log('criando nova janela para ${url}') 
 })
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant except old Electron version.